# How to annotate custom Named Entity tags on full-parsed tree?

Tags: nltk, text-parsing, named-entity-recognition

With `nltk.chunk.tagstr2tree`, "We can divide a string of bracketted tagged text into chunks and unchunked tokens, and produce a Tree.":

```
>>> s = "[ Pierre/NNP Vinken/NNP ] ,/, [ 61/CD years/NNS ] old/JJ ,/, will/MD join/VB [ the/DT board/NN ] ./."
>>> t = nltk.chunk.tagstr2tree(s, chunk_label='NP')
>>> t.pprint()
(S
  (NP Pierre/NNP Vinken/NNP)
  ,/,
  (NP 61/CD years/NNS)
  old/JJ
  ,/,
  will/MD
  join/VB
  (NP the/DT board/NN)
  ./.)
```

Instead of shallow-parsed structure above, Let's say we are now have a full-parsed tree below.

```
>>> print(treebank.parsed_sents()[0])
(S
  (NP-SBJ
    (NP (NNP Pierre) (NNP Vinken)) # want to add some NE info, namely "NAME".
    (, ,)
    (ADJP (NP (CD 61) (NNS years)) (JJ old)) # "AGE"
    (, ,))
  (VP
    (MD will)
    (VP
      (VB join)
      (NP (DT the) (NN board)) # "Organization"
      (PP-CLR (IN as) (NP (DT a) (JJ nonexecutive) (NN director)))
      (NP-TMP (NNP Nov.) (CD 29))))
  (. .))
```

Now I want to add some information, namely 'Name', 'Age' and 'Organization' on the corresponding tokens of `Pierre Vinken`, `61 years old` and `the board`.
So it is basically similar to the chunking task of the first example, but the difference is that I want to annotate custom NE tags on the tree which has already been FULL-PARSED.

*Is there any handy way (tools like a corpus reader in NLTK) to add NE tags on this parsed tree? I want to do this manually.*

[image: Finkel and Manning (2009)]

Maybe the figure 1 of [this paper](http://nlp.stanford.edu/pubs/joint-parse-ner.pdf) illustrates my needs well. 
it says "Knowing that a phrase is a named entity, and the type of entity, may help in getting the structural context, and internal structure, of the entity correct",
and so it tries to "augment the parse tree with named entity information, for input to our learning algorithm".

I want to manually annotate my custom NE tags on FULL-PARSED tree, because I also believe it would help understand the grammatical structure of NEs, and useful for training NER chunker in the future.

Any tips or relevant tools/references would be appreciated. 
Thank you so much!